# Href inside nav ul does is not responding

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I can't figure out what is getting in the way here. I have a simple nav that looks like this:

```
<nav>
    <div class="artists">
        <a href="#">OPEN</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/newpage">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The opacity of `ul` is initially 0, until the user clicks on OPEN, after which the "dropdown" list is displayed:

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex; /* bc there are actually more things than one category */
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--black-75);
}

.artists ul {
    width: max-content;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 16px;
    padding: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 3rem;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.artists a:focus + ul {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

This works, however when I click on the first item in my list, which should take me to `/newpage`, nothing happens. It almost seems like something is in the way?? What is particularly odd is that when I hover over that link, Chrome displays the correct address in the bottom-left of the browser, so it knows what I want to do. Setting `z-index` to 9999 doesn't seem to do anything...

```css
nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex; /* bc there are actually more things than one category */
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--black-75);
}

.artists ul {
    width: max-content;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 16px;
    padding: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 3rem;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.artists a:focus + ul {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="artists">
        <a href="#">OPEN</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/newpage">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: remove `pointer-events: none;`, its a nav with things you want to click right?

Comment: @zgood yes, but I don't want them to be clickable while the dropdown has 0 opacity. Only after a:focus and the list itself id displayed

Comment: does `display:none` work for you? or are you trying to achieve some kind of fade animation with opacity?

Comment: exactly, there's a small fade and displacement that happens... oddly I tried display:none just to see and that has the same problem.

Comment: E.g. I cannot right click and open link in new tab

Comment: your dropdown menu currently relies on you focusing the first "parent" a tag. when you right click to open new tab or click the child a tags you lose focus of the "parent" since they are not nested (and dont nest <a> tags).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the details and summary elements for a simpler accessible approach?

The problem above is caused because the parent ul element has pointer-events: none; set which the children are inheriting. The approach I’ve suggested won’t require you to change opacity or pointer-events, so should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of playing with pointer events try with pseudoelements above and bellow the ul tag

```css
        nav {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            /* bc there are actually more things than one category */
            border-bottom: 1px solid var(--black-75);
        }

        .artists ul {
            width: max-content;
            /* position: absolute; */
            margin-top: 16px;
            padding: 30px;
            list-style: none;
            line-height: 3rem;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all 1s ease;
            z-index: 9999;
            position: relative;
        }
        .artists ul::after {
            position: absolute;
            content: " ";
            /* background-color: red; */
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1;
            transition: z-index 1s;
        }
        .artists a:focus+ul::after {
            z-index: -100;

        }
        .artists a:focus+ul {
            opacity: 1;
        }
```

```html
    <nav>
        <div class="artists">
            <a href="#">OPEN</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/newpage">TEXT</a></li>
                <li><a href="/newpage2">TEXT</a></li>
                <li><a href="/newpage3">TEXT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: How about I show a live example...what I need is for the menu to hover over the content below it like this https://thomasnicholson.ca/sacredrealism/ ... you will see when you click on "artists" ... clicking on the first name in the list should bring you to a new page, just like if you click on "label" in the main categories. What you suggest is almost what I am looking for, but the space for the menu itself has already been reserved...

Comment: you can try wrapping the ul tag inside a div, giving this div the absolute position and the ul the relative position. that involves updating your css selectors. Nevertheless after looking at your website I highly recommend you to toggle display none to the dropdowns, becuse having them transparent can drive to bad user experience

Comment: Display none is what I would usually have done, but I came across a tutorial with the cute fade and repositioning transition that relies on opacity and thought it might be easier... Surprise.

Comment: You can add the display properties to your current CSS with the opacity and transition properties, and that will give you the cute fade animation, can you share all the code of your live example? I tried to make a copy  to it to implement the dropdown but seems you are  dinamically loading many htmls and assets